# How to display a 5 star rating with multiple graduations (full and half stars) in pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display (yes display only, no clicking) the average rating of an entity with a typical 5-star-marker. This marker should be adjustable via JavaScript so I can set/update the current average rating. This should be include graduations (full and half stars).

The solutions I already found use special fonts, images and are to complex (in my opinion) (e.g. use to many html elements). I would prefer a solution with minimal code with is easy to integrate.

Comment: @Paulie_D he's answering his own question ...

Comment: That doesn't make it a **good question** or remove the responsibility to ask it the right way.

Comment: We don't dump general requests as questions and then answer them on SO. That's what personal blogs are for.

Comment: I did research but none of the solutions I found did what I wanted. That's why I thought it might be helpful to share my solution. I think this is what the feature "answer your own question" is for. Not everybody has a personal blog to do so and using Stack overflow will allow much more people to find that solution. So why should I add an incomplete code snippet / solution to the question if I answer it right away?

Comment: you said it --> *none of the solutions I found did what I wanted.* : so you simply didn't find a solution that is suitable for *you* and you shared one that is good for *you*. So there is no issue or problem, but a simple preference

Answer (score 5):

Here's my own solution. All you have to add in your HTML is to nested divs, which then are styled via the stylesheet contained below:

`<div class="stars"><div class="percent"></div></div>`

You can then simply set the amount of stars in percent (20% per star; 10% for a half star) by setting css `width` of the `.percent` element. (For demonstration purposes the percent value is added in the html here, but it can be added or modified later via JS)

```css
.stars {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    font-size: 50pt;
   height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.stars:before { 
    content: "\2606\2606\2606\2606\2606";
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
}

.stars .percent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

.stars .percent:after { 
    content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
    color: rgb(255, 200, 0);
}

li {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width:  0%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 10%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 20%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 30%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 40%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 50%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 60%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 70%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 80%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 90%;"></div></div></li>
<li><div class="stars"><div class="percent" style="width: 100%;"></div></div></li>
</ul>
```

The above snippet shows all graduations from 0% to 100% in 10% steps. Note that smaller steps will not equally spread inside the stars, because the width adjustment does not consider the space between the stars - but 10% steps are fine.

Comment: this solution also use too many html element, it can be reduced

Comment: here is a similar one with less of code : https://jsfiddle.net/9j1oaqnk/4/  as a side note, z-index is useless when you don't have position set